# gSoap fault SOAP-ENV:MustUnderstand[no subcode]

Tags: visual-c++, soap, gsoap, onvif

I am building a web service for ONVIF camera using gSoap.
I have generated the header and the source files using the core wdsl provided by ONVIF at https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/.

However, every time i make a request from the client i get the below error in the function `soap_begin_serve(soap)`:

```
SOAP 1.2 fault SOAP-ENV:MustUnderstand[no subcode]
"The data in element 'Security' must be understood but cannot be processed"
```

What does the above error means and how can i fix it?

EDIT: This is what i receive at the camera side:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetSystemDateAndTime"
Host: localhost:8090
Content-Length: 261
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Close

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetScopes"
Host: localhost:8090
Content-Length: 905
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Close

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Header><Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><UsernameToken><Username>admin</Username><Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">WFz21zL8rch8LRoxAPzgHRMBbr0=</Password><Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">9y79ka0xD02oCIw6GAoIPwEAAAAAAA==</Nonce><Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-05-21T08:15:58.902Z</Created></UsernameToken></Security></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetScopes xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: There is a problem in UsernameToken/Security header. Can you post the SOAP message that you are sending to camera?

Comment: posted the request received at the camera.thanks.

Comment: do i have to separately configure gsoap for WS-Security?

Answer (score 1):

> SOAP 1.2 fault SOAP-ENV:MustUnderstand[no subcode]
>   "The data in element 'Security' must be understood but cannot be processed"

This means that you will need to enable WS-Security to authenticate:

1. add `#import "wsse.h"` to the `.h` header file (aka. service and data binding "interface file") for soapcpp2 to process.
2. in your source code, `#include "plugin/wsseapi.h"`
3. in your source code, provide the user credentials before sending the request with `soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenDigest(soap, NULL, "username", "password");`
4. compile the source code with compiler flag `-DWITH_OPENSSL` and compile your application code base together with `plugin/wsseapi.c`, `plugin/smdevp.c`, and `plugin/mecevp.c` (the `plugin` directory is in the gSOAP distro path), and of course also compile `stdsoap2.c` or `stdsoap2.cpp` and other generated files;
5. link with OpenSSL `-lssl -lcrypto`, and perhaps `-lz` if compression is desired;
6. when using the full WS-Security plugin capabilities with gSOAP (digital signature and/or encryption), you should **compile all your source code** with compiler option `-DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_DOM -DWITH_GZIP` and also compile `dom.c` or `dom.cpp` together with your code.

See also [the WS-Security plugin](https://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html#wsse_6_2) for gSOAP.

Hope this helps.